# How to interpret incidence rate ratio?

Tags: negative-binomial-distribution, ratio

I ran a negative binomial model and then decided to also calculate incidence rate ratio but I am not sure if I understand the ratios correctly. My dependent variable is the number of individuals who joined X organizations per city. My main independent variable is the percentage of educated individuals per city. I got a 1.93 for my main independent variable. Does it mean that a one percent increase in the percentage of educated people per county will result in 1.93 increase in the number of people who joined the X organization?

Answer (score 3):

It means that for a one percentage point increase in the percentage of educated people per county, you expect the number of individuals who join the X organization to increase *by a factor of 1.93*, which means you multiply by 1.93. So, for a one percentage point increase in educated people, the number of individuals who join the organization nearly doubles.

Comment: Thank you very much. So, if one gets an IRR of 1 for a variable, it means that the variable does not have any impact?

Comment: That's right. When you get a confidence interval for an IRR, if it contains 1, you can't reject the null hypothesis.